# I'm currently making a profile page for my system, what is the correct syntax for this?

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db",$conn);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where empID");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $test['empID'];
  echo "<p>".$test['fname']."</p>";
}
?>
```

I don't know what to do. I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users where empID` - this will return all the rows with non-zero non-null empIDs

Comment: I suggest you expand your question to explain what it is you want this code to do. It looks to me like @GurV is probably right but without that explanation it's hard to know

Comment: Also: You should use the mysqli functions rather than the mysql functions, which have been deprecated for a very long time. (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) They're no harder to use, so there's no excuse for using the old deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli is dreprecied use PDO:

```
<?php

#backslash is important to spécified you want a native class
use \PDO;

class Connexion{

    private static $instance;
    private $server_setting = [];
    private $database;

    #use singleton to instanciate
    private function __construct($file){
        $this->file = require($file);
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function get($key){
        return (isset($this->file[$key])) ? $this->file[$key] : new \Exception('Unknow server identifiant');
    }

    public function connect(){
        try{
            $database = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$this->get('db_name').';host='.$this->get('db_host'),
                                 $this->get('db_user'),
                                 $this->get('db_pass'),
                                 array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
                                       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
            #For accent like : éêèïçõ...
            $database->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        }catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    protected function sinInstance($file){
        return (self::$instance == NULL) ? self::$instance = new MySQL($file) : self::$instance;
    }

    protected function getDatabase(){
        return $this->database
    }
}

?>
```

class for making request:

```
<?php

use Connexion;

class Statement extends Connexion{

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($file){
        $this->pdo = parent::sinInstance($file)->getDatabase();
        return $this;
    }

    public function mine(){
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    #You can also put general function here like:
        public function creat(){}
        public function select(){}
        public function update(){}
        public function delete(){}

    #thinking about entity and function get_object_vars();
}

?>
```

The config file:

```
<?php
# File to config.
return array(
    "db_name" => "mydb",
    "db_host" => "localhost",
    "db_user" => "root",
    "db_pass" => ""
);

?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php

const SERVER_SETTING = 'root/to/my/server-setting/file'
use Statement;

$pdo = new Statement(SERVER_SETTING)->mine();

    $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytab');
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->fecthAll();

#or

$pdo = new Statement(SERVER_SETTING);

    $statement = $pdo->mine->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytab');
    $statement->execute();
    #for entity: statement->setFetchMode();
    $statement->fetchAll();

?>
```

Good luck